# NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem... ordering

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Whenever I create an `NSLayoutConstraint` via `+constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`, I always seem to end up putting the items in the wrong order, and then I have to reverse them. It is so annoying, and I can't seem to figure out any way to be able to tell before actually running the code how it will turn out. For example, I would expect this code to position `view` 16 points to the right of the leading edge of `self.view`, which is intuitive to me given the order of the arguments:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leadingMarginConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:16];
```

However, the opposite happens. The leading edge of `view` is 16 points to the left of the leading edge of `self.view`. Same with this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *verticalSpacingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:view2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:16];
```

I am expecting the top of `view2` to be 16 points below the bottom of `view1` but the opposite happens. The top of `view2` is 16 points above the bottom of `view1`.

Can anyone explain to me how this works? What is the significance of the argument order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's Programming Guide provides the answer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1

Specifically, constraints represent this equation: y = m*x + b.

Where 'x' and 'y' are views attributes, 'b' is the constant, and 'm' is the multiplier.  'x' and 'y' map to the first and second items in the method you're calling, respectively.  So if y represents view 2's top, x will be view 2's height + 16.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the equation that defines constraints. For your first example, what you are saying is,

```
self.view.leading = view.leading x 1 + 16
```

self.view.leading has to be 0 (by definition), so for that equation to work, the leading edge of view needs to be -16.